# How to record data in a database by clicking a BUTTON?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this PHP code that allows me to know I have friends registered. When you go to your profile, there is the button that says Add, and if the user is my friend it says ADDED. I would like to help me to that when I press the button, it runs me some code to insert the ID for this user in the database (if not my friend). Whether through ajax, not is. But of course when I click.

```
<?php

include_once('conexion.php');
if ($user != $my_id) {
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "registros");
    $quer = mysqli_query($mysqli,
        "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (User_one = '$my_id'AND User_two = '$user') OR (User_two = '$user' AND User_one = '$my_id')");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($quer) == 1) {
        $mensaje = "<button onclick= 'DeleteFriend(event)'>Already Friends</button>";
    } else {
        $mensaje = "<button onclick='agregarAmigo(event)'>No Friends</button>";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but I guess this is what you mean; From my limited knowledge if I was to do something like that, I would do it this way. You should write a simple script that inserts the ID into the database and name it maybe "insert.php" . Then the `<button id='button'>` should contain an id. Then you can use jquery to check if the button is clicked and when it is clicked, use the jquery ajax method to send the id as post data to the "insert.php" script -

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: "user id should be here",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#message").html(response); //optional. Just to know that everything works.             

    }
});
```

Then in your insert script you would check to ensure that there is an ID and then run the INSERT statement

```
<?php 
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   if (isset($id)){
     $sql="INSERT INTO ......";
//then place a variable to check if the insert statement was succesful and return a success message to be displayed in the paragraph tag with an id of "#message"
   if ($succesful){ 
      echo " Friend added succesfully ";
   }else{
      echo "There was an error";
  }  

}
```

Comment: I don't know how to put the user id(format) in data:(ajax).

Comment: do i need to add "$(document).ready(function(){})" in the ajax code?

Comment: Yes you need to . As you need to whenever you're writing jquery to prevent errors.

Comment: You can also use the $.post short way of doing things.